# Flutter Google Maps Info Window Text Color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, google-maps-flutter

I implemented google maps on flutter for all platforms:

google_maps_flutter:      ^1.0.6

google_maps_flutter_web:  ^0.1.0+8

Everything works nice. I also added an InfoWindow, but unfortunately the text color is always red on the Web version and I'm also not able to change it or don't see where to change. On iOS and Android it is black.

I tried Inline Styles as on the regular JS implementation, e.g.:

```
'<div style="color:black;">' + infoWindowText + '</div>';
```

and

```
'<p style="color:black;">' + infoWindowText + '</p>';
```

But it didn't worked.

The colors in the Theme and widgets are as defined black and white. But not red.

Any ideas?

Thx in advance!